# VBA: looping through worksheets using nested For Each having worksheet as variable

Tags: vba, excel

Newbie at vba here. I'm trying to apply a simple For Each loop (which nullifies cells < 0) to all worksheets in the workbook by nesting this inside another For Each loop.

When I try and run my code below I get an error and I'm not sure if it has anything to do with having worksheet as a variable within a Set statement.

Can't seem to figure this out/find a solution.

Thanks

```
Sub deleteNegativeValue()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim res As Range

For Each ws In Workbooks(1).Worksheets

Set res = ws.Range("1:1").Find("Value", lookat:=xlPart)
lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In Range(ws.Cells(1, res.Column), ws.Cells(lastRow, res.Column))
If cell < 0 Then cell = ""
Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error and on which line?

Comment: Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. Error seems to be on the second For Each bit

Comment: Besides the suggestion below, you will want to put in a test to make sure that "Value" is found, you are probably returning a range object with nothing in it.

Comment: Instead of `Dim cell As Range` I think it should be `Dim cell As Cell`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Cell as range is correct. for excel vba.

Comment: It initially did find "Value" in my worksheet until I introduced the loop through each worksheet bit. I've check that "Value" does exist in every worksheet and the error persists even with the below change.

Comment: Then you may be looking in the wrong workbook, if more than one is open then Workbooks(1) may point to a different one, try my code below.  It will name any sheet that "Value" is not found.  It will help pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub deleteNegativeValue()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim res As Range

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    Set res = ws.Range("1:1").Find("Value", lookat:=xlPart)
    lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    If Not res Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, res.Column), ws.Cells(lastRow, res.Column))
            If cell < 0 Then cell = ""
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "No Value found on Sheet " & ws.Name
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

There needs to be a check on the Find method, to ensure that something was found

Comment: Thank you so much for this:)

Comment: The check on the Find was definitely needed.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleteNegativeValue()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim res As Range

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set res = Intersect(ws.Rows(1), ws.UsedRange).Find("value", LookAt:=xlPart)
    If Not res Is Nothing Then
        ws.Columns(res.Column).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).Replace What:="-*", Replacement:="", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, LookAt:=xlWhole
    Else
        MsgBox "No Value found on Sheet " & ws.Name
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

which should run faster since it doesn't iterate through every cell of each column and restrict the `Find` method range to the used one instead of the entire row.

the only warning is that the first row of all searched in sheets must not be empty...

Answer (score 0):

Try the second for-each this way:

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, res.Column), ws.Cells(lastRow, res.Column))
```